# Why won't my VBA code execute properly on a RDS server but it works on 2 of my local machines?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have VBA code that is supposed to loop through each link in a JavaScript table, then it clicks 2 buttons and moves on to the next link. It works fine on the 2 hardware machines I have at my desk but I also have a profile on our remote desktop server.

The Remote profile will only go into the first link and ignore/drop the rest. I have the same permissions on my local works stations as the remote server.
Any help would be much appreciated

I've reloaded my user profile and refreshed my group policies. I have re-coded the module to not call additional Subs and I've coded it to nest Subs. Sometimes it will work fine and loop through a few times then revert back to only doing the first link.

```
Sub Look_up()

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Set allLinks = appIE.document.getElementById("tblItems").getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In allLinks
    appIE.Navigate link
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    For Each wd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If wd = "Internet Explorer" Then
           Call LookUp.NextIEWin
        End If
    Next wd
Next link
End Sub



Sub NextIEWin()
    If InStr(UCase(wd.document.Title), "ITEM") <> 0 Then
                Do Until IsObject(wd.document.getElementById("btnLook")) = True
                DoEvents
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                Loop
                    If wd.document.getElementById("drpReason").Value = 20369 Then

                        Do Until IsObject(wd.document.getElementById("btnAddItem")) = True
                        DoEvents
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                        Loop
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
                        Range("F" & 2).Value = Error_1

                        wd.document.getElementById("btnAddItem").Click
Else
                        wd.document.getElementById("btnLook").Click
                        Do Until IsObject(wd.document.getElementById("btnAddItem")) = True
                        DoEvents
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                        Loop
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
                        wd.document.getElementById("btnAddItem").Click
                    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

My

```
For Each link In allLinks
```

Works fine on my local workstations. It seems to break and only process the first link and drop the rest in my RDS sessions

Comment: Did you got any error or warning message? Did you try to debug the code step by step? It can be possible that some IF conditions get false generates this result. First I suggest you to debug the code and inform us any error or warning message. It can help us to understand the issue in better way. Also make sure that you have similar kind of IE settings on that machine.

Comment: I guess your `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))` line after `appIE.Navigate` is the issue while 3 seconds is enough to wait on one computer/link it can be not enough for another. This method is not very reliable, because you cannot know if the action you are waiting to finish is actually finished in that amount of time. Instead check and wait if the page was fully loaded by using `While appIE.readyState <> 4 Or appIE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend`

Comment: Deepak-MSFT there are no errors my links just drop out of the alllinks
Phe is just a pause while the new window opens. it's actually 2 seconds longer than it needs to be I was using it to try to figure out what was going on. The links open a popup if that sorry if that wasn't clear from the code. I haven't added comments yet. If I do remove that application.wait it doesn't really an effect the sub.

Comment: Still it is not clear where your code get stuck or stopped. Try to inform us the exact line where your code get stopped. Try to wait for some more time using Application.wait to see the output. You can also check that all the links are existed and your code is able to retrieve it. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Emein Go through the code step by step using F8 wait every step untir your IE is ready. If it then works there is a timing issue.